# Template class without template arguments, gets instanciated with no compile errors

Tags: templates, c++17

Consider this code:

```
template< typename T >
class C
{};

int main(void)
{
    C<int> var;

    C v = var;
}
```

The last line should be an error. Playground here: https://godbolt.org/z/aN5rGM

If I change the standard to 03, 11 and 14, it fails with

> use of class template 'C' requires template arguments

Which is what I expect. But from C++17 it builds. What's up?

Comment: [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Comment: @rafix07 indeed. massive update. I postponed to later the careful read on this and forgot about it. Now got caught off guard lol :)